HLS.js playlist could not be loaded and the video doesn't work on my web site
I faced an issue with autoplaying videos on my website, particularly on mobile devices. I've successfully implemented video autoplay for desktop screens. But mobile screens are displaying an error message in Chrome:

I'm working with HTML/CSS/JavaScript and using HLS.js to play videos in chunks. All video content, including chunks and playlists, is hosted on AWS storage.
Here's the HTML code snippet for embedding the video:
<div class="background-video w-background-video w-background-video-atom">
    <video id="video" autoplay loop muted playsinline data-object-fit="cover"
           data-wf-ignore="true">
    </video>
</div>

And below is the JavaScript code I'm using to switch playlists based on screen resolution:
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var videoSrc = window.innerWidth <= 1024 ?
            'https://d2vsrh5hfn32bm.cloudfront.net/output_mobile_playlist.m3u8' : // Mobile URL
            'https://d2vsrh5hfn32bm.cloudfront.net/output_playlist.m3u8'; // Desktop URL

        if (Hls.isSupported()) {
            var hls = new Hls();
            hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
            hls.attachMedia(video);
            hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
                video.play();
            });
        } else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
            video.src = videoSrc;
            video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
                video.play();
            });
        }
    });

Also I noticed the strange behavior. I am located in Poland. But if I change my IP address to US via VPN, the video will be work well.
It will be great to read some advices.

sounds like you've answered your own question - these videos, for whatever reason, are georestricted at the source.
